# RegEx JavaScript: Match consecutive single line comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a RegEx to parse groups of single line comments.

Given this input:

```
//line 1
//line 2
//line 3

//line 4
//line 5
//line 6
```

I expect to have two matches: Lines 1-3 and 4-6. With my current RegEx `(^\/\/[\S\s]+$)` I have one match: Lines 1-6, although there is an empty line in between.

The problem is that `\s` matches any whitespace character, so the blank line is included. But at the same time, line break *are* part of the RegEx – but only when the line starts with `//`, so I am stuck.

How can I prevent the RegEx from matching the blank line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because I want to learn it

Comment: If this can't be done with RegExes, then it's also knowlege :) I am just curious because initially I thought it should be possible

Comment: ok, good luck ...

Comment: Not an expert but this seems to work `^\/\/[\S\s]+?\s$`

Comment: @Brahma Dev: I like your solution even more!

Comment: It's not as good as some of the other suggestions but just to illustrate a different approach to the problem: `/^\/\/[^]*?$(?!\n\/\/)/gm`

Comment: @skirtle: Did you mean to write `/(?:^\/\/[^^]*?$(?!\n\/\/))/gm` perhaps? `[^]` on its own throws an error. Unfortunately, on SO you cannot go back and "correct" comments ...

Comment: @cars10m Where are you seeing an error? It works for me in Chrome and Firefox. regex101 seems to understand my intent too.

Comment: Sorry @skirtle, I really did not mean to offend, but my [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ostoQn/1) with your pattern `^\/\/[^]*?$(?!\n\/\/)` shows the error "[^ Character class missing closing bracket". Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: @cars10m No offence taken, I was worried that `[^]` might be dodgy when I wrote it. Your regex101 is using `pcre` and not `JavaScript`. It wouldn't surprise me if there's a JS implementation somewhere that doesn't understand `[^]` but it's easily replaced with something like a more traditional `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
/(^\/\/[^\n]+$\n)+/gm
```

see here https://regex101.com/r/CrR9WU/1

This selects first the two `/` at the beginning of each line then anything that is *not* a newline and finally (at the end of the line) the newline character itself. There are two matches: rows 1 to 3 and rows 4 to 6. If you also allow "empty comment lines like `//` then this will do too:

```
/(^\/\/[^\n]*$\n)+/gm
```

**Edit:**
I know, it is a little late now, but Casimir's helpful comment got me on to this modified solution:

```
/(?:^\/\/.*\n?)+/gm
```

It solves the problem of the final `\n`, does not capture groups and is simpler. (And it is pretty similar to Jan's solution ;-) ...)

Comment: You can make more simple if you put the anchor `^` out the group, you don't need the `$` anchor. `.` *(the dot)* matches all except `\n` like `[^\n]`. Also your pattern will fail if a line of comment is at the end of the string without a newline after it or if a comment line doesn't have characters after the slashes: `/^\/\/.*(?:\n\/\/.*)*/gm`

Comment: @Casimir: Thanks for pointing that out! Good alternativa regexp!

Answer (score 2):

This is what modifiers are for:

```
(?:^\/{2}.+\n?)+
```

With `MULTILINE` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qEcWia/1/).

---

Broken apart, this says:

```
(?:       # a non-capturing group
    ^     # start of the line
    \/{2} # //
    .+    # anything else in that line
    \n?   # a newline, eventually but greedy
 )+       # repeat the group
```